# How to configure cookies in next-auth (using keycloack) for SSO(single sign on) ?¿

Tags: authentication, next.js, single-sign-on, keycloak, next-auth

I have a simple setup, where i'm using next-auth along with keycloack provider in order to have an authentication/authorization system.

The problem i'm facing, is that, i need SSO, and i've been trying to make some changes (specially on the cookies side) but haven't been able to get what i want.

Let's say we have two sub-domains `stuff.example.com`  -  `damn.example.com`, and i want to login just once to keycloack using next-auth, and been able to use this two web applications with the same user without having to login every time i go to another sub-domain.

So far, this simple setup works as expected

```
export default NextAuth({
  debug: true,

  providers: [
    KeycloackProvider({
      clientId: "next-sso-client-1",
      clientSecret: "SSO-example",
      issuer: "http://localhost:8080/realms/SSO-example",
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, profile, account }) {
      if (profile) {
        token.profile = profile;
        token.idToken = account?.id_token;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      // @ts-ignore
      session.user.profile = token.profile;
      return session;
    },
  },
})
```

if i login, default cookies are set and i can get user info.

[image]

**But**, if i try to get the main domain and set it to my custom cookies so that every sub-domain can identify these cookies and get user data and not having to login every time i go to another website, everything just breaks.

```
const obtenerDominio = (url: string) => {
  const dominio = new URL(url).hostname.split(".");
  return dominio
    .slice(0)
    .slice(-(dominio.length === 4 ? 3 : 2))
    .join(".");
};

const useSecureCookies = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL?.startsWith("http://");
const cookiePrefix = useSecureCookies ? "__Secure-" : "";
const hostName = obtenerDominio(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL!);

export default NextAuth({
  debug: true,

  providers: [
    KeycloackProvider({
      clientId: "next-sso-client-1",
      clientSecret: "SSO-example",
      issuer: "http://localhost:8080/realms/SSO-example",
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, profile, account }) {
      if (profile) {
        token.profile = profile;
        token.idToken = account?.id_token;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      // @ts-ignore
      session.user.profile = token.profile;
      return session;
    },
  },

  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `${cookiePrefix}next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        path: "/",
        secure: useSecureCookies,
        domain: hostName == "localhost" ? hostName : "." + hostName, // add a . in front so that subdomains are included
      },
    },

    callbackUrl: {
      name: `${cookiePrefix}next-auth.callback-url`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        path: "/",
        secure: useSecureCookies,
        domain: hostName == "localhost" ? hostName : "." + hostName, // add a . in front so that subdomains are included
      },
    },

    csrfToken: {
      name: `${cookiePrefix}next-auth.csrf-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        path: "/",
        secure: false,
        domain: hostName == "localhost" ? hostName : "." + hostName, // add a . in front so that subdomains are included
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**No cookies are set**, can't even get to login form.

[image]

And if i comment the custom **csrsToken**, it lets me login, and the default cookie is set, but can't get user data, and the other cookies, like **next-auth.session-token** are not set.

[image]

**What should i do, how can i get this to work ?¿**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one specific error

this line of code is wrong

`const useSecureCookies = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL?.startsWith("http://");`

you have to change it to `https`, so the value of `useSecureCookies` would be false, and the cookie option of `secure` would be false as well, and that's how it should be, since in local development we normally don't use https, only in prod.

with this change, we would be able to setup the custom cookies with custom domain and have SSO.